# java.lang.AbstractMethodError when trying to run Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I updated my Android Studio, and ever since I get:

> Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jetbrains.settingsRepository.IcsApplicationLoadListener.beforeApplicationLoaded(Lcom/intellij/openapi/application/Application;)V
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.fireBeforeApplicationLoaded(ApplicationImpl.java:539)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:481)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

when trying to run Android Studio. When I Google the error:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jetbrains.settingsRepository.IcsApplicationLoadListener.beforeApplicationLoaded(Lcom/intellij/openapi/application/Application;)

I get only one result of the same problem, but was asked 2 weeks ago and wasn't answered.

I tried re-installing SDK, re-installing Android Studio and no success.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the Settings Repository plugin from the Android Studio plugins directory using an external file manager. (The directory depends on your OS, which you didn't specify in your question.)

Comment: I am facing the same issue with 2.1.2 version of Android studio. I tried deleting the Settings Repository as you mentioned. I am using Windows 7 64 bit system. Is there any other solution?